# Can I increase the strength of H'aanit's monster, Linde?

Tags: octopath-traveler

Linde is a pretty great monster to have in the beginning of the game with three strength. With slash and pounce attacks, along with the mere fact that slash attacks all, practically invaluable.

However I've progressed far enough into the game that I'm regularly coming across monsters with five or more strength. Considering I'm holding weapons that can deal much more damage, I hardly call Linde unless I hope to get a slash attack (to try to attack enemies' weak points).

Can I somehow increase Linde's strength? Or is it stuck at three strength forever?

For more context, I started with H'aanit and she's at level 40 now. Haven't started on her second chapter yet as I'm completing other lower level chapters first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Linde's never get stronger, which is a fact that makes H'aanit challenge option somehow unreliable.

You can tame stronger monsters tho and/or simply makes H'aanit strong enough to not need Linde.